# Will I lose root & CWM when I upgrade via Kies (Galaxy Note 2)?

Tags: updates, clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-kies, device-firmware, recovery-mode

I rooted my Samsung Galaxy Note 2 with ClockworkMod Recovery. My Samsung Galaxy Note 2 is using Official Samsung firmware from T-Mobile and ClockworkMod Recovery.

In the future Samsung may release a new firmware update for my phone. If I update firmware using Samsung Kies, is it possible? will I lose root? how about the recovery? does it go back to the original recovery instead of ClockworkMod Recovery?

Comment: someone did it before?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will lose root (OTA survival mode at root application does not always work).

Recovery loss depends on package, provided with upgrade (it varies on availability of recovery.img).

Comment: But you will not lose it if you have a custom kernel that automatically applies root after update (as the case with Galaxy Y).